# Log/Trace information in SDL Tridion

Tags: 2011

Is there a way I can get complete log/trace for users being logged in to CME 2011 SP1.
For example: Is it possible to retrieve a list of all the users currently logged in to the CMS or users logged/performed some activity across a time period.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no.

IIS gives you all of this information (and way more) in its logs. You can probably use tools like [IIS Log Analyzer](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2009/06/iis-log-analyzer) to compile this information for you.

An alternative way is to use the Event System to log what happens for you, like we do in the "[Tridion 2011 Reporting](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-reporting/)" project (look at the event system code there, it logs to a MongoDB database).

Comment: Was the "Tridion 2011 Reporting" project move somewhere else (since Google Code was retired)?

Answer (score 5):

As Nuno mentions, IIS logs provide this info.  Here is a link to a Q&A that is very much in context of what you're asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503734/retrieving-user-login-time-in-sdl-tridion-2011